# how to set selected multiple combo box based on array

Tags: php, arrays, combobox

I have two sets of array ,first array contains all categories called "all", and second array contains selected categories called "selected", I want to populate this concept to multiple combo box,

```
$all = [
        0 => [
            'id'=>1,
            'name' => 'news'
        ],
        1 => [
            'id'=>2,
            'name' => 'tips'
        ],
        2 => [
            'id'=>3,
            'name' => 'trick'
        ],
        3 => [
            'id'=>4,
            'name' => 'review'
        ]
    ];

    $selected = [
        0 => [
            'id'=>2,
            'name' => 'trick'
        ],
        1 => [
            'id'=>4,
            'name' => 'review'
        ],
    ];
```

I've try to do foreach in foreach , but i have duplicated data when show in combo box, i want to have all data from "all" shown with selected data from "selected".

i just solved my problem in deferent way , first i add default pair of key and value "sel"=>0 in "all" array set, then i loop trough array "all" and array "sel" to get similar value and when it match change sel key to 1 ,this code for further explanation

```
public static function compare($sel,$all){
    // add sel key with default value = 0
    foreach($all as $k=>$v){
        $all[$k]['sel'] = 0;
    }

    foreach($all as $k=>$v){
        foreach($sel as $k2=>$v2){
            // when match change sel to 1
            if($v['id'] == $v2['id']){
                $all[$k]['sel'] = 1;
            }

        }
    }
    return $all;
}
```

final result :

```
$all = [
        0 => [
            'id'=>1,
            'name' => 'news',
            'sel' => 0
        ],
        1 => [
            'id'=>2,
            'name' => 'tips',
            'sel' => 0
        ],
        2 => [
            'id'=>3,
            'name' => 'trick',
            'sel' => 1
        ],
        3 => [
            'id'=>4,
            'name' => 'review',
            'sel' => 1
        ]
    ];
```

just add if condition when $all['sel'] = 1 they should be selected, thanks all :D

Comment: Please show your current foreach loops

Comment: please wait a minutes

Comment: `$x = '';
        foreach($all as $a){
            foreach($selected as $sel){
                if($a['id'] == $sel['id']){
                    $x .= '<option selected>value here</option>';
                }else{
                    $x .= '<option>value here</option>';
                }
            }
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the intersection of both arrays with `array_uintersect` and a custom callback function (`compare`).

```
function compare($a, $b){
    if($a['id'] == $b['id']){
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}


$res =  array_uintersect($selected, $all,"compare");
print_r($res);

>Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => trick ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 4 [name] => review ) )
```

After that you only need to loop through the final array and set the corresponding check boxes.

If you want to compare by name just create another callback function.

```
function compare2($a, $b){
    if($a['name'] == $b['name']){
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , but what actually the "compare" callback does when array_intersect() function compares the values of two (or more) arrays, and returns the matches.

Comment: The `compare` function will get a value from each array and check if the "id" (compare) or "name" (compare2) equal. If they equal it will return 0 meaning the values are equal. If the are not we return 1. This way it determines which values to return from `array_uintersect`. You cannot use `array_intersect` for your array consists of arrays and you are not able to specify a callback function. I hope this makes it clear.

Answer (score 0):

The duplicates are caused by the inner for loop continuing to create select elements even after it has found a selected element. You can avoid having an inner loop and using php's in_array() function to check if $all is in $selected like this:

```
$x = '';
foreach($all as $a){
    if(in_array($a, $selected)){
        $x .= '<option selected>'.$a['id'].'Selected </option>';
     }else{
      $x .= '<option>'.$a['id'].'Not selected </option>';
     }
}
echo $x;
```

Note that in_array will check all values of the elements, so for example element with id 2 but different name will appear as not selected. You may want to change both names to tips. I hope that helps.